# How can I print the Tag value (SDK aws ec2) in the Vaadin Grid?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vaadin

I've a trouble to find how can I get the tag value and add it in the Vaadin grid.

I created my grid to get some AWS information (thought EC2 web services).

```
Set<Instance> instances = ec2Client.getInstances();

Grid<Instance> instanceGrid = new Grid<>();
instanceGrid.addColumn(Instance::getKeyName).setCaption(IStringConstants.NAME_LABEL).setId(IStringConstants.NAME_LABEL);
instanceGrid.addColumn(Instance::getTags).setCaption(IStringConstants.TAGS_LABEL).setId(IStringConstants.TAGS_LABEL);
instanceGrid.setItems(instances);
```

However, I get this for the column Tags : `[{Key: Test Key,Value: }, {Key: Name,Value: Test Value}].`

And I just want the value `Test Value`

So I tried to get the value by doing a

```
for(Instance instance : instances){
   instance.getTags().stream().map(c -> c.getValue()).toString()
}
```

However, this will return a String and Vaadin grid doesn't authorized string if it's not a property name.

So, to sum up  :

- I use Vaadin 8
- I use the SDK for AWS ec2
- I use the Instance.java and Tag.java are in the `com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was pretty simple to fix :

```
 instanceGrid.addColumn(instance -> instance.getTags().get(instance.getTags().size()-1).getValue())
```

**Edit**, Finally, I used :

```
   instanceGrid.addColumn(instance -> getTagName(instance));
   public static String getTagName(Instance instance) {
        if (instance.getTags() != null) {
            for (Tag tag : instance.getTags()) {
                if (tag.getKey().equals("Name")) {
                    return tag.getValue();
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: What happens when there are no tags?

Comment: It print an empty string.

Comment: Somehow I feel you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because when size is 0, then `getTags().get(0 - 1)` may not be able to comply with your desire :-)

Comment: I'll double test it, because I thought about that too. I can make a condition to avoid this error. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @morfic, I updated the code, I think it's cleaner like that... and should avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. What do you think about the code? Thanks